# How to attach image url in seed file with rails active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, rails-activestorage

Recently upgraded from `Rails 4` to `Rails 7.0.4.3`

I now get an error

```
Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #Tempfile:/var/folders/m3/5b_093ms4n7254zlxjr2fthw0000gn/T/open-uri20230418-66934-yzytt1
```

Seed.rb

```
require 'open-uri'

spot1 = Spot.create(name: 'Spot 1', description: 'This is spot 1', latitude:42.0, longitude:-73.0, maxGuests: 2, price: 200, address: 'address' , city: 'forbidden_city', host_id: user1.id)

spot1.photos.attach(URI.parse('https://www.example.com/example.jpg').open, filename: "example.jpg")
```

spots_controller.rb

```
def create
        @spot = Spot.new(spots_params)

        if @spot.save
            render :show 
        else 
            render json: @spot.errors.full_messages, status: 422
        end

    end

    private
    def spots_params
        params.require(:spots).permit(:name, :description, :latitude, :longitude, :maxGuests, :price, :address, :city, photos: [])
end
```

The seeding works without me trying to attach an image

I've tried saving the photo to a public s3 bucket

`spot1.photos.attach(io: open('https://example-seeds.s3.amazonaws.com/example.jpg'), filename: "example.jpg")`

and get this error message

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen.
```

Both methods used to work before update.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need use such syntax

```rb
require 'open-uri'

spot1.photos.attach(io: URI.open("https://some.domain/example.jpg"), filename: "example.jpg")
```